# pandas vectorize one valid signal in 5 rows

Tags: pandas

I want to find the first valid signal in the dataframe. A valid signal is defined that there is no signal in its preceding 5 rows.
The dataframe is like:

```
    entry
0       0
1       1
2       0
3       0
4       1
5       0
6       0
7       0
8       1
9       0
10      0
11      0
12      0
13      0
14      0
```

The entry signal on row 4 is not valid because there is a signal on row 1. Every signals will negate any signal in the following 5 rows.

I implement this by using an apply function with a parameter recording the signal row counter. 
The code is as following

```
import pandas as pd
def testfun(row, orderinfo):
    if orderinfo['countrows'] > orderinfo['maxrows']:
        orderinfo['countrows'] = 0

    if orderinfo['countrows'] > 0:
        orderinfo['countrows'] += 1
        row['entry'] = 0

    if row['entry'] == 1 and orderinfo['countrows'] == 0:
        orderinfo['countrows'] += 1
    return row

if __name__ == '__main__':

    df = pd.DataFrame({'entry':[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
    orderinfo = dict(countrows=0, maxrows=5)

    df = df.apply(lambda row: testfun(row, orderinfo), axis=1)
    print(df)
```

output is:

```
    entry
0       0
1       1
2       0
3       0
4       0
5       0
6       0
7       0
8       1
9       0
10      0
11      0
12      0
13      0
14      0
```

But I am wondering if there is any vectorized way to do this? Because apply is not very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

You need `rolling` with `min_periods=1` and `sum` less than or equal `1` and compare against `entry` column

```
(df.entry.rolling(4, min_periods=1).sum().le(1) & df.entry).astype(int)

Out[595]:
0     0
1     1
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     1
9     0
10    0
11    0
12    0
13    0
14    0
Name: entry, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Hi, I retest the method and I found this maybe not correct, if entry on row 4=1, then it will negate the entry on row 8, which is not correct, Because row 1 has negate row 4 already.

Comment: ah, your code starts counting 1 from `entry=1` while `rolling` starts counting from next item. Just change to `....rolling(4...` instead of `5`.  I edited answer to change it to `4`.